# how to add different base templates for different languages of same page in django cms

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

How can i add different base templates for different languages of same page in django cms?

I am trying to set a page and show it in different languages. And for all the languages, i need to use a different base template.

I am completely new django cms. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create different page trees per language.

Every page has only one template. Use `{% trans %}` and `{% blocktrans %}` for translating string in it. Or `{% if request.LANGUAGE == "en" %}`.

If the templates really differ that much: don't add other languages to pages... but create different page trees with only one language.

Comment: I have a page and against that page i have different templates in each language and i just need to load them on /en /ru /gr etc urls.

What i have done is that i have created a page and added languages for that page but as base template is same for each language specific page it just loads a single template. What i want is that if user changes the language for a page, it should load my translated template in other language but what it is doing right now is that it just loads the same base template because every language specific page has same base template.

Comment: Every page has only one template. Use {% trans %} and {% blocktrans %} for translating string in it. Or {% if request.LANGUAGE == "en" %}. If the templates really differ that much: Don't add other languages to pages... but create different page trees with only one language.